# Как лучше хранить элементы

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, list, коллекции

Дано около 6000 5-ти значных чисел их нужно между собой умножать и сравнивать.Что лучше использовать для хранения массив,лист,или строку? Точное количество элементов не известно.

Comment: а строка-то тут причем, если вы собираетесь арифметические операции над числами проводить?

Comment: 6000 5тизначных чисел можно хранить как заблагорассудится, это практически ничто для современных систем

Comment: @rdorn я могу их постоянно к типу Int приводить)))

Comment: @tym32167Спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

> Точное количество элементов не известно

Если так, то лучше использовать `List<T>`, в него можно в любое время добавить и убрать элементы.

```
List<int> li = new List<int>();
li.Count; /*возвращает количество элементов*/
li.Add(59); /*Добавляет элемент с значением 59 в конец списка*/
li.RemoveAt(1); /*Удаляет элемент под индексом 1 (начало индексации с нуля)*/
li.ToArray(); /*Создает массив с списка*/
```

Подробнее можешь прочитать в статьях о списках в C#, а также других коллекциях, таких как `HashSet<T>`, `SortedList<U, V>` или `Queue<T>`.